# Enable button with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable a Button when the User entered a valid E-Mail in an Input field.

Here is my Code:

```
    //validate Mail
  var testEmail =    /^[ ]*([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})[ ]*$/i;
  jQuery('input#HdC_mail').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    if (testEmail.test(jQuery(this).val()))
    {
       jQuery(this).css({ 'border':'1px solid green'});
       $("#vali").text('');

       document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;

     } else
     {
       jQuery(this).css({ 'border':'1px solid red'});
       $("#vali").css({ 'color':'red'});
       $("#vali").text('Das ist keine gültige Mailadresse');
     }
   });
```

And the HTML:

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <p id="vali"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" disabled="true" value="Absenden">
</div>
```

The text is changed but the Button is still disabled???

[image: Example]

I hope you can help me...

Comment: And why wouldn't it be, you never change the `#submit` button in the else clause ?

Comment: @adeneo — Why would that matter? It's the `if` clause that turns off the `disabled`

Comment: You're right, I'm guessing bad choice in ID then, and that the input is inside a form.

Comment: As an aside, have you tried using an HTML5 `input` tag of type email? Doing so would help you avoid your incorrect email regex, give a better user experience and allow you to query that field to toggle the submit button.

Comment: The code as posted, works just fine -> https://jsfiddle.net/zhsbgbb2/

Answer (score 0):

First, the **disabled** attribute does not have a **true/false** value. You either write it in your HTML markup as `disabled="disabled"` or just `disabled` (if you like minimization and don't care about XHTML compliance)

Second, you'll need to replace

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
```

with

```
$("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
```